# fancybox jquery/js conflict mega

Tags: jquery, fancybox, megamenu

I'm building a site and using fancyBox (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) and DD Mega Menu (http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddmegamenu.htm) but they are conflicting.  Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: It may be a js error somewhere. Share a link with the issue to help you to find it.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this one

```
jQuery.noConflict()
```

or you should visit this webpage

[jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: I don't think that jQuery.noConflict() will solve the issue since the megamenu of reference is also jQuery code. You should use jQuery.noConflict() when using jQuery with other js frameworks like prototype or mootools. I would think that there is a js error somewhere rather than a conflict.